# Android : How to check that no function has been performed recently(say last 1 minute) on the current Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How to check that no function has been performed recently(say last 1 minute) on the current Activity(Activity1).
and if the Activity1 does not perform any task for the last one minute, then Activity1 should finish automatically.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions it's bad practice.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814182/to-close-the-current-activity-and-start-another-activity-if-the-user-does-not-do  You were given answers and a link to the FAQs.

Comment: If I'm not getting the answer and you people are in hurry of closing the question.. what one should do???????

Comment: Try the answers provided.  If they do not work, or you have a specific question, then come back.  Please read the FAQs.